# Entity Field Query - Most efficient way to get authors of nodes

Tags: database

I have a content type which contains fields which I am filtering my results on. Of these results, I wish to get the email address of the user who authored the node.

Currently I am using an Entity Field Query to get the list of nids. There can be thousands of matching nodes.

To get the email addresses of the authors of the nodes I do a `node_load_multiple` with the nids of my EFQ, and then a `user_load_multiple` with the uids of those nodes.

Is there a way to cut out a few of those steps with EFQ? Or will performance not be as big of an issue as I think it is?

Here is a code example:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
  $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
        ->entityCondition('bundle', 'application')
        ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
        ->fieldCondition('field_one', 'value', $value1)
        ->fieldCondition('field_two', 'tid', $value2)
        ->fieldCondition('field_three', 'tid', NULL, 'IS NOT NULL');
  $result = $query->execute();

  if (isset($result['node'])) {
    $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
    $uids = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
      $uids[$node->uid] = $node->uid;
    }
    $users = user_load_multiple(array_keys($uids));
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing a lot of potentially unnecessary loads. Unless you need those nodes at some point on the page request, you will be doing a lot of unnecessary database reads.

I would EFQ to get the node list, and then do another query to just get the `$uids`. This example will retrieve the node list you're looking for:

```
$efq = new EntityFieldQuery();
$efq->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'application')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_one', 'value', $value1)
  ->fieldCondition('field_two', 'tid', $value2)
  ->fieldCondition('field_three', 'tid', NULL, 'IS NOT NULL');
$result = $efq->execute();

if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $query = db_query('SELECT DISTINCT uid FROM {node} WHERE nid IN :nids', 
    array(':nids', array_keys($result['node'])));

  $uids = $query->execute->fetchCol();
  $users = user_load_multiple($uids);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think an EFQ is not the best way of doing this? I've contemplated just using a single db_query or db_select as all I really need are the users' mail fields. I thought I'd try to avoid having to write a more complex multiple join query, but that might just be the smartest and most efficient way.

Comment: @dieuwe Unless the query is on a high volume page, I don't worry about things like this.  A db_select() will be faster (the EFQ includes an automagic node_access, which you should always use for the node table), but I like the convenience of EFQ so I don't need to remember table/column names.